# How to hide Liferay Portal from being index in any of the popular search engine?

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp

We have been using Liferay Portal to serve as Extranet Portal for our company. We can see that our portal being listed in Google's search. **We don't want our portal to be shown in popular search engines like Google**. However, we still want to keep our portal on Internet (not on Intranet).

Could anyone help with any idea, please.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Suyash

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the robots.txt file of your site from the Liferay user interface.

Adding a robots.txt file in your site tells the web crawlers to stop indexing your site. For more information about robots.txt rules and instructions see:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard
- https://www.robotstxt.org/

For the Liferay 7.2 version, to configure the robots.txt file on the Liferay user interface you have to go to:

1. Site Builder => Pages => click on the cog next to "Public Pages"
2. Open the "Advanced" tab => scroll to the "Robots" section
3. Fill the robots box with you robots.txt instructions

Other Liferay versions can have a slightly different interface, but the robots section will be available in the "Public Pages" advanced configuration.

You have more information about this in the Liferay documentation, see:

- https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360029132671-Configuring-Page-Sets
- https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360029132691-Advanced-Page-Set-Options#robots